# Apology to site

Tags: discussion

I would like to apologize for my reaction to criticism of a post I made related to Christian Zionism.  I was really unfair to some of the people who made comments and reacted very badly to my answer being deleted.  I would like to especially apologize to @Caleb, who was actually supportive but made a good case for why my answer was deleted.

I am not offering this as any sort of excuse, but there are many Christians in Gaza and the West Bank who some of us feel are oppressed by the Israeli nation-state.  International Orthodox Christian Charities - a pan-Orthodox Christian organization that coordinates relief efforts by Orthodox Christians in the United States - [has supported a fund for 20 years designed to help especially people in the West Bank and Gaza](https://www.iocc.org/where-we-work/jerusalem-west-bank-and-gaza).  I let my feelings of solidarity with those in these areas who are suffering get in the way of objectively addressing an otherwise straightforward question that was posted.

Comment: I didn't see any of the goings-on, but thank you for displaying a commendable level of maturity.

Comment: you are one of my favorite contributors. Thank you for demonstrating the warmth of the heart needed to apologize.  I missed the contratemps (yay) and hope all is well with you.

Answer (score 2):

**Apology to site**

Do not know about the others, but as for myself and many others I would like to thank you for you commendable action of apologizing to those on this site.

Sometimes, we can easily get carried away with an emotional response and say something that we later regret, but it is truly Christian to apologize to the whole site.

As for me, apology accepted. We can all learn from this!